QGIS layer attributes change unpredictably after saving and loading from ESRI gdb file
I have this temporary layer, navarro_rivers_soils, which is the result of a spatial join. It has the attributes I expect. In the image below I have selected a section which appears in dark blue, and is "Well drained."

The "Make permanent..." option in QGIS does not work, at least for saving to ESRI File GeoDatabase (gdb) format. So I drag the layer into the gdb in the Browser pane, which seems to save it, and then I drag that saved layer from the Browser pane back into the Layers pane, which gives me the same layer but without the "temporary" marking. I assume that changes I make to that layer will be saved in the corresponding file.
I apply the same symbology to this new saved layer as to the old temporary layer, and it becomes clear that the attributes have changed in unpredictable ways. I don't know if this is a bug or something I'm not understanding is happening.

A number of river segments have changed color despite having the same symbology. Selecting the same section as before shows now only one row instead of many, and it has nothing in the muggat_drclasswet attribute, which is why it displays very pale blue.
Why is this happening and how can I work around it?

Please provide the QGIS's and OS's exact full version info.

3.40.0-Bratislava b56115d8743 on Ubuntu 24.04.1

I suggest you to create an issue report at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/ providing a project file and any needed layer and detailed step-by-step instruction in order to make a replicate the issue on his system and try to fix the bug, if it is actually a bug.

If you had the spatial join save to a gdb instead of a temporary layer does it similarly change attributes?  If you saved your temporary layer to a shapefile or geopackage layers does it similarly change attributes?

@John Saving directly to a gdb (a new one; it seems the dialog provides no way to save a layer to an existing gdb) and then importing the saved layer produces different buggy behavior: the imported layer has exactly one segment, a little chunk of river toward the northwest. All the rest of the layer data seems to be lost.

@John If I save the join to a gpkg and then import the layer, it contains no data whatsoever. If instead I select my temporary joined layer and click "Make permanent..." and save to a gpkg, I get a Save Error: "Creation of field fid failed (OGR error: Wrong field type for fid)."

The fid error is interesting might be useful info for someone more knowledgeable than me.  What data format is the original layer prior to the join? Just as a boilerplate response, you might run a geometry check on your layer prior to the spatial join.   Assuming that doesn't help you have a lot of info to submit to an issue report following Andrea's suggestion.

I have worked around the problem by converting the gdb files to gpkg and simply not trying to use File GeoDatabases with QGIS, which seems not ready for general use. Things are working well with GeoPackages.
